# Debugging shell scripts in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm using Bash Debug 0.1.0 vscode extension for debugging a bash script.

When the script tries to source another script, for example:

```
source tools/common_tools.sh
```

I get this error:

```
 Unable to open 'common_tools.sh': no provider for tools/common_tools.sh.
```

What is the reason of this error and how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Suggestion - ditch VSCode for debugging shell scripts and just paste it into [ShellCheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/). Or use the intended `bash -x yourscript.sh`. Using VSCode for a job it was never intended for seems like a recipe for disaster.